# Decode URL Safe Base64 in JavaScript (browser side)

Tags: javascript, base64, gmail-api

I am using Gmail's API to get emails from my account. The body of the message is delivered in a "URL safe base64" format. What is the best way to decode this for use? I have found some nodejs solutions, but no client side ones. window.atob does not work since it is URL safe.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 44):

For posterity,

```javascript
atob(data.replace(/_/g, '/').replace(/-/g, '+'))
```

As stated by the spec https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-5 however because this uses `atob()` it does not support unicode characters and thus requires [a polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding#Solution_2_%E2%80%93_rewrite_the_DOMs_atob()_and_btoa()_using_JavaScript%27s_TypedArrays_and_UTF-8).

Comment: Was this meant to be atob(data).replace(/_/g, '/').replace(/-/g, '+') instead

Comment: Reading from the Base64 version of common codec, it should be the inverse:btoa(data)
                                    .replace(/\//g, '_').replace(/\+/g, '-'))),

Comment: jmnben: no we want to replace the '_' and '-' before we do the decoding.

Comment: what about the . (dot) ? shouldn’t it be replaced by = (equal) ?

Answer (score 11):

Finally found it. This does URL Safe decoding

https://github.com/dankogai/js-base64