# URL-safe base64 decoding for R

Tags: r, encoding, character-encoding, base64

I don't know if it's just R being notoriously hard to search for but I can't seem to find a URL-safe base64 decoder for R.

Does anyone know of one ?

**Edit** I've used various decoders, the `RCurl::base64decode()` function as well as online ones and the results are somewhat inconsistent.

I admit I don't understand the full details of what differentiates a "URL-safe" base64 decoder but find it dismissive to have my question closed in a matter of minutes due to a moderator's misunderstanding of what I'm asking before anyone gets a chance to answer.

**Edit 2** The equivalent in Python is [`base64.urlsafe_b64decode(s)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html#base64.urlsafe_b64decode), and as yet noone has implemented this in R.

Using `library(sos)` as recommended in the comments brings up 3 packages, and as expected a Google search would have found them had they URL-safe methods.

- `base64::decode()` has just two parameters, `input` and `output`, i.e. only works on files, and attempting this on my string produces a mangled output.
  [image]
  The only other methods in the package are `encode()` and `img` (for image file base64-string encoding)
- `base64enc::base64decode()` follows much the same, though can use a text connection rather than solely a file input. Again, no option to use a modified URL-safe alphabet
- `RCurl::base64Decode()` can only take text input (befitting a stream-handling package), and a `mode` parameter can be set to either *raw* or *character*. It doesn't seem that either mode permits altering the decoding alphabet.

The Python docs explain that a URL-safe alphabet

> substitutes `-` instead of `+` and `_` instead of `/` in the standard Base64 alphabet.

I'd be interested to know how to use a custom alphabet. If I understand correctly the 'raw' mode has already applied the alphabet, and thus mistranslated.

The example above is the body of an email I retrieved through the Gmail API, which base64-encodes with such a URL-safe encoder:

```
PGRpdiBkaXI9Imx0ciI-SGksPGJyPjxicj5JIGNhbiYjMzk7dCBpbnN0YWxsIHhwcyBiZWNhdXNlIGR1cmluZyBjb21waWxlIEkgZ2V0OjxkaXY-PGJyPjwvZGl2PjxkaXY-PGZvbnQgZmFjZT0ibW9ub3NwYWNlLCBtb25vc3BhY2UiPlRNTE1hdGguY3h4OjUxOjE5OiBmYXRhbCBlcnJvcjogVE1hdGguaDogTm8gc3VjaCBmaWxlIG9yIGRpcmVjdG9yeTxicj48L2ZvbnQ-PC9kaXY-PGRpdj48Zm9udCBmYWNlPSJtb25vc3BhY2UsIG1vbm9zcGFjZSI-PGJyPjwvZm9udD48L2Rpdj48ZGl2PjxkaXY-PGZvbnQgZmFjZT0ibW9ub3NwYWNlLCBtb25vc3BhY2UiPsKgI2luY2x1ZGUgJnF1b3Q7VE1hdGguaCZxdW90OzwvZm9udD48L2Rpdj48ZGl2Pjxmb250IGZhY2U9Im1vbm9zcGFjZSwgbW9ub3NwYWNlIj7CoCDCoCDCoCDCoCDCoCDCoCDCoCDCoCDCoCDCoF48L2ZvbnQ-PC9kaXY-PGRpdj48Zm9udCBmYWNlPSJtb25vc3BhY2UsIG1vbm9zcGFjZSI-Y29tcGlsYXRpb24gdGVybWluYXRlZC48L2ZvbnQ-PC9kaXY-PGRpdj48Zm9udCBmYWNlPSJtb25vc3BhY2UsIG1vbm9zcGFjZSI-bWFrZTogKioqIFtUTUxNYXRoLm9dIEVycm9yIDE8L2ZvbnQ-PC9kaXY-PGRpdj48Zm9udCBmYWNlPSJtb25vc3BhY2UsIG1vbm9zcGFjZSI-RVJST1I6IGNvbXBpbGF0aW9uIGZhaWxlZCBmb3IgcGFja2FnZSDigJh4cHPigJk8L2ZvbnQ-PC9kaXY-PC9kaXY-PGRpdj48YnI-PGZvbnQgZmFjZT0iYXJpYWwsIGhlbHZldGljYSwgc2Fucy1zZXJpZiI-RG8geW91IGhhdmUgYW55IGlkZWEgd2hlcmUgSSYjMzk7dmUgZ29uZSB3cm9uZywgb3IgaG93IEkgbWlnaHQgZml4IGl0PyBGdXJ0aGVyIGRldGFpbHMgb2YgaG93IEkgd2VudCBhYm91dCBpdCBhcmUgPGEgaHJlZj0iaHR0cHM6Ly9naXRodWIuY29tL2xtbXgvZGV2bm90ZXMvd2lraS9JbnN0YWxsaW5nLUNFUk4mIzM5O3MtUk9PVC1mcmFtZXdvcmsiPmhlcmU8L2E-wqBhbmQgZnVsbCBzY3JlZW5zaG90IGF0dGFjaGVkLjwvZm9udD48L2Rpdj48ZGl2Pjxmb250IGZhY2U9ImFyaWFsLCBoZWx2ZXRpY2EsIHNhbnMtc2VyaWYiPjxicj48L2ZvbnQ-PC9kaXY-PGRpdj48Zm9udCBmYWNlPSJhcmlhbCwgaGVsdmV0aWNhLCBzYW5zLXNlcmlmIj5JIHRyaWVkIG1hbnVhbGx5IGFkZGluZyBpbiB0aGUgZmlsZXMgdGhlIGVycm9yIG1lc3NhZ2Ugc2FpZCB3ZXJlIG1pc3NpbmcsIGJ1dCBldmVudHVhbGx5IGl0IGdhdmUgYSBkaWZmZXJlbnQga2luZCBvZiBlcnJvciBhbmQgSSBkZWxldGVkIHRoZXNlIGFkZGl0aW9uYWwgZmlsZXMgYWdhaW4gKHNlZSB0aGUgbGluayBhYm92ZSkuPC9mb250PjwvZGl2PjxkaXY-PGZvbnQgZmFjZT0iYXJpYWwsIGhlbHZldGljYSwgc2Fucy1zZXJpZiI-PGJyPjwvZm9udD48L2Rpdj48ZGl2Pjxmb250IGZhY2U9ImFyaWFsLCBoZWx2ZXRpY2EsIHNhbnMtc2VyaWYiPkkgaG9wZSB5b3UgbWF5IGJlIGFibGUgdG8gYWR2aXNlLCBJJiMzOTt2ZSBydW4gb3V0IG9mIGlkZWFzIGFuZCBleHBlcnRpc2Ugb24gaG93IGVsc2UgdG8gcHJvY2VlZC48L2ZvbnQ-PC9kaXY-PGRpdj48Zm9udCBmYWNlPSJhcmlhbCwgaGVsdmV0aWNhLCBzYW5zLXNlcmlmIj48YnI-PC9mb250PjwvZGl2PjxkaXY-PGZvbnQgZmFjZT0iYXJpYWwsIGhlbHZldGljYSwgc2Fucy1zZXJpZiI-QmVzdCB3aXNoZXMsPC9mb250PjwvZGl2PjxkaXY-PGZvbnQgZmFjZT0iYXJpYWwsIGhlbHZldGljYSwgc2Fucy1zZXJpZiI-PGJyPjwvZm9udD48L2Rpdj48ZGl2Pjxmb250IGZhY2U9ImFyaWFsLCBoZWx2ZXRpY2EsIHNhbnMtc2VyaWYiPkxvdWlzPC9mb250PjwvZGl2PjwvZGl2Pg0K
```

which an online URL-safe decoder will give as

> <div dir="ltr">Hi,<br><br>I can't install xps because during compile I get:<div><br></div><div><font face="monospace, monospace">TMLMath.cxx:51:19: fatal error: TMath.h: No such file or directory<br></font></div><div><font face="monospace, monospace"><br></font></div><div><div><font face="monospace, monospace"> #include "TMath.h"</font></div><div><font face="monospace, monospace">                   ^</font></div><div><font face="monospace, monospace">compilation terminated.</font></div><div><font face="monospace, monospace">make: *** [TMLMath.o] Error 1</font></div><div><font face="monospace, monospace">ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘xps’</font></div></div><div><br><font face="arial, helvetica, sans-serif">Do you have any idea where I've gone wrong, or how I might fix it? Further details of how I went about it are <a href="https://github.com/lmmx/devnotes/wiki/Installing-CERN's-ROOT-framework">here</a> and full screenshot attached.</font></div><div><font face="arial, helvetica, sans-serif"><br></font></div><div><font face="arial, helvetica, sans-serif">I tried manually adding in the files the error message said were missing, but eventually it gave a different kind of error and I deleted these additional files again (see the link above).</font></div><div><font face="arial, helvetica, sans-serif"><br></font></div><div><font face="arial, helvetica, sans-serif">I hope you may be able to advise, I've run out of ideas and expertise on how else to proceed.</font></div><div><font face="arial, helvetica, sans-serif"><br></font></div><div><font face="arial, helvetica, sans-serif">Best wishes,</font></div><div><font face="arial, helvetica, sans-serif"><br></font></div><div><font face="arial, helvetica, sans-serif">Louis</font></div></div>

The `RCurl` function gives a truncated and patchy decoding:

> <div dir=\"lt\001ȈHi,<br><br>I can't install xps because during compile I get:<d\001\xa5\xd8<br></div><d\001\xa5\xd8<font face=\"monospace, monospace\">TMLMath.cxx:51:19: fatal error: TMath.h: No such file or directory<br></fo\001\xb9\xd0</d\001\xa5\xd8<div><font face=\"monospace, monospac\001\x94\x88<br></font></div><div><d\001\xa5\xd8<font face=\"monospace, monospace\"> #include "TMath.h"</font></div><div><font face=\"monospace, monospace\">                   ^</fo\001\xb9\xd0</d\001\xa5\xd8<div><font face=\"monospace, monospac\001\x94\x88compilation terminated.</fo\001\xb9\xd0</d\001\xa5\xd8<div><font face=\"monospace, monospac\001\x94\x88make: *** [TMLMath.o] Error 1</fo\001\xb9\xd0</d\001\xa5\xd8<div><font face=\"monospace, monospac\001\x94\x88ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘xps’</fo\001\xb9\xd0</d\001\xa5\xd8</d\001\xa5\xd8<div><\001\x89\xc8<font face=\"arial, helvetica, sans-seri\001\x98\x88Do you have any idea where I've gone wrong, or how I might fix it? Further details of how I went about it are <a href=\"https://github.com/lmmx/devnotes/wiki/Installing-CERN's-ROOT-framework\">here<

While the [online base64 decoder](http://www.komeil.com/toolbox/base64decoder) I was using won't decode it at all, reporting an error.

I'll have to write something to use a custom alphabet myself if noone knows a way to do this with existing R packages. I'd prefer not to have to invoke Python, if possible.

Comment: In the old days before Google adopted R in a big way I used to use `r-project` as a search term with pretty good success. These days i use the `findFn`-function in pkg:sos. I find a ton of stuff including a package named .... wait for it... `base64`. So maybe you need to define "url-safe" and say what it is you cannot do that you need to do..

Comment: It's [related to the alphabet used to decode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#URL_applications), I'm not an expert but it's a genuine difference in the decoding which other languages have libraries for. I've just tried that package (I was using RCurl's `base64decode()` method) and the result [wasn't a success](http://i.imgur.com/tRMpenR.png) - it's the message body from Gmail API, some [URL-containing base64](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28100601/decode-url-safe-base64-in-javascript-browser-side)... Thanks for the tips on finding R-related things, I'll definitely use those

Comment: I think you might mean "encoder".  But I'm going to close this as "looking for a package" ...

Comment: No I don't mean encoder... it's a question regarding how to perform something using the language, since when was that not permitted ? I can provide examples to show what I've been struggling with for the past hour or so here, and I'm not asking for opinions on preferred software - it seems that there is a function not available and I want to confirm, entirely within the guidelines for what's [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Your question is not closed (yet anyway). It takes 5 close votes to close and so far it has only gotten one. But failing to put in a reproducible example would be anotehr reason to close, so why not spend a little effort on improving the question?

Comment: FWIW, I'm not a moderator (just a user). Your question is clearer now, thanks. It's not clear to me whether "is there/has someone written a function to do <x>?" falls within the scope of "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource".  Maybe worth a Meta question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... that was embarrassingly easy.

`base64Decode(gsub("-","+",gsub("/","_",strtodecode)))`

Sorry to answer my own question, it seems way more complicated than it is

**Edit** this actually has to be `base64Decode(gsub("-","+",gsub("_","/",strtodecode)))` for the case I'm working on, but for an example the above worked - there are multiple base64 alphabets.