# How to fix DOMException Decoding Email Message

Tags: gmail-api

I am using the GMail API to retrieve messages. The messages are machine generated, so follow a similar format.

Although most of the messages are fine, I am getting a DOMException using atob to decode the message body for a subset of the messages.

I think I've narrowed it down to messages that have a section in it that looks like:

```
     --------------------- Sudo (secure-log) Begin ------------------------ 


     jeremy => root
     --------------
     /usr/bin/docker                -   5 Time(s).

     ---------------------- Sudo (secure-log) End -------------------------
```

Specifically I think that the problem happens because of the `=>`.

The error is:
`Error parsing DOMException: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.`

Code fragment:

```
    gapi.client.gmail.users.threads.get({
       userId: 'me',
       id:     thread.id
    })
    .then(function(response){
       var
          content,
          message = response.result.messages[0],
          rawContent = message.payload.body.data;

    try{
       content = atob(rawContent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This thread helped me [Decode URL Safe Base64 in JavaScript (browser side)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28100601/decode-url-safe-base64-in-javascript-browser-side/44528376#44528376)

```
    rawContent = rawContent.replace(/_/g, '/').replace(/-/g, '+');
```

Fixed it up.